# hive regex find pattern and return it in select statement

Tags: sql, regex, select, hive

I would like to extract 3 words before the `selay dervice` but the query returns an empty column :(

```
with a as (
        select * from tablename1 b 
        where lower(ptranscript) rlike 'selay dervice'
        )
        select *,regexp_extract(lower(a.ptranscript),'([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+){3}selay dervice',0)  from a
```

##########update 1

as pointed by Raid earlier, in Hive we cannot use `\s` and have to use `\\s`. I updated the above regex accordingly and it works

```
with a as (
            select * from tablename1 b 
            where lower(ptranscript) rlike 'selay dervice'
            )
            select *,regexp_extract(lower(a.ptranscript),'([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s+){3}selay dervice',0)  from a
```

Comment: Do you mean you get no output? Or a wrong piece of text?

Comment: updated the question and explained the output

Comment: Can you show a sample of the inputs you get? Without that it's impossible to help you. You regex works as long as those words only have the characters you included. BTW, note you do `lower()` but then look for `A-Z` as well.

Comment: Is this an Azure Databricks DB? From Microsoft's help, the last parameter `0` means returning the whole matched string, not the 3 words you want. To get the 3 at once you may need to add extra parenthesis: `(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+){3})`, as otherwise the groups are the individual words. Testing the regex [here](https://regexr.com) works fine. It matches `This is a selay dervice`, and with the extra parenthesis you get `This is a`.

Comment: Another comment: `rlike` is for regular expressions, it might be faster to use `like '%selay dervice'%` instead. Following from my comment above, I think you need to use this: `regexp_extract(a.ptranscript,'(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+){3})selay dervice',1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
with a as (
        select * from tablename1 b 
        where lower(ptranscript) rlike 'selay dervice'
        )
        select *,regexp_extract(lower(a.ptranscript),'(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+ ){3}selay dervice',0)  from a
```

Note that if there are less than 3 words before *selay dervice* you will get empty results.

I tested similar query in latest apache hive and got something like below:

```
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|               key                |          regex_ext          |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| rlk1 selay dervice               |                             |
| selay dervice k4                 |                             |
| k5 selay dervice ew              |                             |
| thre word b4 selay dervice       | thre word b4 selay dervice  |
| four word be four selay dervice  | word be four selay dervice  |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Edit 1:
Result does not vary with or without ?
All 3 versions below gives same result.

1. '(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+ )'
2. '([a-zA-Z0-9]+ )'
3. '([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s)'

As per docs \s matches any white space not just spacebar

Comment: what did you change? what does `?:` in regex mean? it just return a column with `null` in it

Comment: @Raid, the user wants to get those 3 words, so adding `?:` to make them non-capturing groups does no good IMHO.
@user2543622, can you please reply to my comments above?

Comment: @Andrew tried but not getting any output :( - just a blank column

Comment: @user2543622, can you *please* **carefully read each one** of my comments above and reply? Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: I tested this in latest apache hive. As I do not have your exact data I tested something like below:
```|               key                |          regex_ext          |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| k5 selay dervice ew              |                             |
| thre word b4 selay dervice       | thre word b4 selay dervice  |
| four word be four selay dervice  | word be four selay dervice  |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------+```

Comment: Yes, that's what happens with the original regex as well. That's why I asked for input cases that don't work. Without them there's not much to do.

Comment: @Andrew Original regex posted in questions gives empty values for all

Comment: I don't have a DB that supports `regexp_extract` so I can't test it, but the regex alone works just fine. Even you said *"work same as ([a-zA-Z0-9]+ ) and ([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s)"*, so I don't see any change in the regex actually (I assume the double backslash was a typo).

Comment: No, \s does not work in hive. \\s works

Comment: how could i update the regex to return 3 words before `selay dervice`? words could contain a-z, 0-9 or even symbols

Comment: @user2543622, could you solve finally?

Comment: yes, `regexp_extract(lower(ptranscript),'(\\S+\\s+){1,3}(?=selay dervice)',0) as three_words1` worked. @Raid's comment - `No, \s does not work in hive. \\s works` was very helpful